# Looking for ways and options to stop the worker process after task completion in celery?

Tags: python, docker, celery

The question context is from the stand point of disposable infrastructure using docker for celery workers.

I am looking out for a option or ways to achieve the following:

- I start a docker container, which starts the celery worker [along with concurrency]
- It waits and picks ups one task per worker
- the workers shutdown after task is completed [success or failure]
- The main process dies after all workers are down.
- I dispose off the container and start a new one.